# Search Multiple Text Files for Similar Data

Tags: arrays, vb.net, data-manipulation

I have multiple text files with similar data, for instance file1 would have the following entry:

test1, 1400

Then file2 would have:

test1, 2400

As all of these files are generated by different programs, is it possible to check through each text file for a similar entry, for instance using the files mentioned above, say I wanted to find test1 from both files and calculate the sum of the score and thus get the following data saved to another text file:

test1, 3800

The Programming Language I am using is VB.NET, currently I have read all of the files using:

```
Dim Array1() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("path")
```

---

My current logic is to get all of the data into a list or a KeyValuePair, where the list will store the username of the user as well with their score which would be summed at this point. I have currently read all of the data from each text file to an array, with each array in the FormLoad Event I have got it into a form where the data is split with a delimiter with the comma. At the start of the program I have an Input Box which asks the user for their Username and stores it in a variable called UserInput. From there this is what I need help achieving, I need the Program to get value from each array and store it in another array where it sorts the data of each user with their scores, from their I can use: `For i = 0 to ar.length - 1` Loop to go through the array and search for the Users username.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, so you will have to show more of your workings and logic. What have you tried to solve the question at hand, and where does it not meet expectations? All you have shown so far is a single line that reads all lines of a file into a single array - which shows no effort at finding similar text, calculating any sums or saving to any other file.

Comment: @AJD I have added what I hope to achieve with what I've done so far. I haven't added the code as it's pretty basic code and I think it would be easier to just write out what it does, however if you want to see the code I would be happy to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach

```
 Dim arr1 As New List(Of String)
 arr1.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("text file 1"))

 Dim arr2 As New List(Of String)
 arr2.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("text file 2"))

 Dim searchstring As String = "test1"
 'You can replace test1 with the string you are searching the text file for

 Dim index1 As Integer = 0
 Dim index2 As Integer = 0
 'Getting the index of the string in the list
 '*******************************************
 For x As Integer = 0 To arr1.Items.Count - 1
      If arr1(x).StartsWith(searchstring) Then
           index1 = x
      End If
 Next
 For x As Integer = 0 To arr2.Items.Count - 1
      If arr2(x).StartsWith(searchstring) Then
           index2 = x
      End If
 Next
 '*******************************************
 Dim split1() As String = Split(arr1(index1), ",")
 Dim split2() As String = Split(arr2(index2), ",")

 Dim sum As Integer = Integer.Parse(Trim(split1(1))) + Integer.Parse(Trim(split2(1)))
 'Writing the sum to another test file, the "output.txt" file would be created on your desktop, you can replace the path's string with your custom location
 Dim path As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "output.txt")
 Dim finaltext As String = searchstring + "," + sum.ToString
 System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, finaltext)
```

The above method creates a new text file "output.txt" on your desktop.

Comment: Thank You for your help, I have adapted the code to suit my needs, one change I made which was causing an error was the last line: Instead of using System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, finaltext) as I was getting a conversion error from string to IEnumerable. I fixed it by using a streamwriter instead so: Using Writer As New StreamWriter("path", true) then below it I wrote: Writer.WriteLine(finaltext) then ending it with: End Using

Comment: One more thing I wanted to know was that, is it possible for the program to read all the non integer values so all the username with something like integer.tryparse then output the text file with the sum of all the usernames?

Comment: what do you mean by the sum of all the usernames?

Answer (score 0):

AJD is correct. You need to make an attempt before posting. I answered because I want practice with Linq. Since you have 2 different types of data, a class or a structure is in order (or use a database). I filled a list of the structure by splitting the lines into the string portion and integer portion; setting the properties of the structure. You can add as many files as you wish to the List. I tested with both the Linq method and the Loop method.

```
Structure TestData
    Public TestName As String
    Public TestScore As Integer
End Structure

Private TestList As New List(Of TestData)

Private Sub AddToList(path As String)
    Dim arr() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    For Each line As String In arr
        Dim arr2() As String = line.Split(","c)
        Dim td As TestData
        td.TestName = arr2(0)
        td.TestScore = CInt(arr2(1).Trim)
        TestList.Add(td)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetSummWithLinq(NameOfTest As String) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = (From Score In TestList
                             Where Score.TestName = NameOfTest
                             Select Score.TestScore).Sum
    Return result
End Function

Private Function GetSumWithLoop(NameOfTest As String) As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    For Each item In TestList
        If item.TestName = NameOfTest Then
            total += item.TestScore
        End If
    Next
    Return total
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p As String = "C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\TestData.txt"
    AddToList(p)
    Dim a As Integer = GetSummWithLinq("test1")
    MessageBox.Show($"The Linq method produces {a}")
    Dim b As Integer = GetSumWithLoop("test1")
    MessageBox.Show($"The Loop method produces {b}")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
My TestData.txt file that I used to test the code.

```
test1, 314 
test2, 740 
test1, 700 
test2, 200
```

Comment: Hey, I liked the solution and implemented it and adapted it to my needs, however I got an error with the line td.TestScore = CInt(arr2(1).Trim) The error stated that index is out of bounds, I tried using a for loop  with i and i +1 to solve it however to no success.

Comment: I didn't add checks to the solution. If the data is always in the format you presented it should work. I have added my test data to my answer. `line.Split` should produce an array with 2 elements. Element (0) being the test name and Element (1) being the score. If one of the elements is missing in the data file or the comma is missing, arr2 might end up with only one element and produce the exception you received.